# Bash script to kill port

Tags: linux, bash, shell, port

At the moment I am learning SSH creating and listening of servers. But I still tend to do it wrong a lot and afterwards my ports are still open. So I am writing a bash script to kill it, but I had a bug I was unable to solve.

**The script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=$(lsof -i:22 -t);set -f;a=(${pid})
for e in ${a[@]}
do
    echo $e
    kill $e || kill -9 $e
done
```

**Behaviour**

@ `echo $e` the shell gives the correct *PID*

but when I do a `lsoif -i:22 -t` when the script is run the *PID* is still open.

What am I missing?

Comment: what happened when you replace `kill $e || kill -9 $e` with `kill -9 $e`?

Comment: When I do the `kill -9 $port` in terminal the process gets killed

Comment: What happened when the script runs the `kill -9 $e` instead of `kill $e || kill -9 $e`?

Comment: It kills the ports... Am i just an idiot? I expected it to kill if not worked use the hard kill

Comment: You don't kill a port; you kill a process listening on the port. There are some TCP/IP options init programs that could affect some of the output shown above. For example, TCP's `SO_LINGER` and `systemd`.

Comment: @jww please elaborate? I did kill the PID's from the port in above script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are willing to kill with the `-9` flag please replace the:

```
kill $e || kill -9 $e
```

with

```
kill -9 $e
```

As mentioned in [nixCraft Logical OR](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Logical_OR)

> ```
> command1 || command2
> ```
>
> command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns a non-zero exit
>   status. In other words, run command1 successfully or run command2.

In the case of

```
kill $e || kill -9 $e
```

The first command (`kill $e`) didn't fail (as the pid was valid), hence the second command wasn't executed.

Comment: @Ludisposed - great! happy to help!

Comment: I would still start with `kill "$e"` to give the process a chance to clean up after itself before exiting. You just need to check with `kill -0 $e` to see if the  process *actually* exited before trying with `kill -9`. Note that just because a process hasn't exited immediately, though, doesn't mean it is not in the *process* of exiting.

Comment: I implemented your idea @chepner But how long should I wait for process to be killed?

Comment: Depends on the process, but you really shouldn't be using `kill -9` in any regular sense. If it were actually necessary, then there is a bug in the program you are trying to kill, and you should either report the bug, or upgrade to a version in which the bug is fixed.

Comment: @chepner the program['ming'] is mine ^^ And I know there are bugs in it, was trying to make an interactive ssh_shell but it keeps hanging. So in order to test it I needed to kill the ports hence the need for this script. Thank you though